# Getting Expected a type specifier error in c++

Tags: c++

I have a pair of base-derived classes ( `IND` = base of `MA`, `MA` = derived from `IND`; `ST`= base of `ST1`, `ST1` = derived from `ST`) and another class (`FD`). I'm trying to use them like:

```
class ST1: public ST{


public:

FD f;

ST1(){};

ST1(FD& a) : f(a) {};

MA abc(f, 10);

};
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
E0757   member "ST1::f" is not a type name
E0079   expected a type specifier
C2061   identifier 'f'
```

All errors are on the `MA abc(f, 10);` line.

Please note that `MA` doesn't have default constructor, takes `FD&, int` arguments and `IND` is a pure virtual class.

Comment: `MA abc(f, 10);` looks like a function declaration, and you should declare its signature. Something like `MA abc(FD f, int i);`

Comment: Is `abc` supposed to be a member *function* or *variable*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's supposed be a member object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MA abc(f, 10);
```

looks to the compiler like a member function declaration, hence the error message - it expects `f` and `10` to be names of types.

For in-line member variable initialisation, you must use curly braces:

```
MA abc {f, 10};
```

but this isn't of much use to you as that would use `f` before you've initialised it.
(In-line initialisation is performed before any constructor initialisation; the order you write them in the class definition is irrelevant.)

Move its initialisation to the initialiser list instead:

```
ST1() : abc(f,10) {}
ST1(FD& a) : f(a), abc(f,10) {};
```

and leave the declaration as

```
MA abc;
```

Comment: I did try the initialing list method, but like I said, MA doesn't have a default constructor. I get the MA's default constructor is deleted error.

Comment: @hmmmmmm You shouldn't be getting it if you're doing the constructor initializer list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried again, still getting `the default constructor of "MA" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function` error

Comment: @hmmmmmm Then you did something wrong when you tried. If you initalise `abc` in the initialiser list, it doesn't need a default constructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @molbdnilo Thanks a ton! It worked after I put `abc(f, 10)` in default constructor of `ST1` as well as in the other constructor.

Comment: @hmmmmmm You mean, like in the answer above?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, sorry. I didn't put `abc(f, 10)` in default constructor thinking I'm not gonna use that constructor anyway.